# Associated records instanciated via nested attributes are not linked both ways

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Issue noticed in Rails 4.0.13

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :avatar
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :avatar
end

class Avatar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
end
```

When instanciating a pair, the avatar is not linked to its author :

```
> author = Author.new(name: 'John', avatar_attributes: {gravatar_id: '41dd2e0c'})
=> #<Author id: nil, name: "John", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

> author.avatar
=> #<Avatar id: nil, author_id: nil, gravatar_id: "41dd2e0c", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

> author.avatar.author
=> nil
```

What can I do to have this association be instanciated both ways?

Comment: You need to `save` `author` to see the `author_id` coming into `avatar`

Comment: Saving is no issue. This is a simplified model, but my issue is that I have validations on the avatar model whose logic depends on the author's attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `inverse_of`:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :avatar, inverse_of: :author
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :avatar
end

class Avatar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, inverse_of: avatar
end
```

Comment: And it even works with polymorphic associations! Thanks for the answer